# Error while calling function in model

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model

I have a model with two functions, like this:

```
<?php

class FotoModel extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function getFotosByCat($cat)
    {
        $this->load->helper("file");
        switch($cat)
        {
            case "bloemen" : return get_filenames("/images/foto/bloemen/");
            case "dieren" : return get_filenames("/images/foto/dieren/");
            case "andere" : return get_filenames("/images/foto/andere/");
        }
    }

    public function getFotoLinksByCat($cat)
    {
        $fileNames = getFotosByCat($cat);
        //i do stuff with $fileNames and provide a return statment..
    }
}

?>
```

I load the model in my controller and tested the second method with some static data for $fileNames and everything works fine. Only when I make a call to the first function (the one with the switch/case statement) from the second (as seen in the code-example) I get an error.

And the thing is I don't even get to see what kind of error. It is because of testing and trying that I know the error MUST be in the first function. Anyone that can help me to solve this one?

Comment: May be there is an error in `get_filenames`. Can you post that code?

Comment: @Sukumar `get_filenames` is a function from CI's file helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$fileNames = $this->getFotosByCat($cat);
```

Comment: Wow, that I didn't see such an 'easy' mistake.. Thanks a lot! ;)

Answer (score -1):

I noticed in your switch you haven't used any break;'s

(im sorry im a SO n00b and I can't for the life of me figure out inline code span..)

Comment: Breaks are not needed when there's a return statement!